# How do I reference a user-entered int?

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

Easy question (I'm a beginner!)... My java program needs to refer back to the user-entered integers stored as variables "a" and "z". These two variables are initialized using a Scanner and the nextInt() method. Here's my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    int z;
    int x;

    System.out.println("Please provide a lower bound (integer): ");
    a = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please provide an upper bound (integer): ");
    z = in.nextInt();
```

So now I need to refer back to these user-entered variables in a for-loop that appears later on, but I do not know the syntax to do this. I need the for-loop to start at "a" and continue one-by-one until "z".

```
for(a ; a <= z ; a++) {
    //code irrelevant to my question
}
```

Java is making it very clear that I cannot just write the variables in the for-loop, so how do I do it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What error are you getting? Doing `for(; a <= z; a++) P` should work, assuming your variables `a` and `z` are in scope.

Comment: Do you just need to refer to a and z, or to all numbers in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do that with a loop counter, let it be `i`:

```
for (int i = a; i <= z; i++) {
    //process i
}
```

In this way you have `i` that starts at `a` and increases up to `z`.

Comment: This works, but I'm still not sure why what the OP posted wouldn't work... I like it when answers explain what the problem was, instead of just showing a possible solution

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm unable to figure that out either, as the OP indicates that that could is irrelevant, but it seems to be the key point of the question.

Comment: It's because `a` by itsels is not a statement. Making it `a=a` would work around the problem. I posted the error in my answer

Answer (score 1):

To start at a and end on z, inclusive:

```
for(; a <= z ; a++) {
```

To stop right before z:

```
for(; a < z ; a++) {
```

This will change the variable `a`.

You don't need to fill that space before the first semi-colon. That's the "initialize counter" spot, and you've already initialized your counter from user input above (before) the loop.

If you don't want `a` to change, then simply duplicate its value into a temporary one, as in @skiwi's answer:

```
for(int i = a; i <= z; i++)  {
```

Here's some good information: https://www.google.com/search?q=for+loop+java

Comment: Probably want to create a new variable instead of modifying `a`

Comment: So java throws an error when you have just `a` in the initializer? And making it `a = a; a < z; a++` would also work (albeit clunkily)?

Comment: I didn't test it, but what's the point of just `a` or `a = a` in the initializer? Or in any context for that matter.

Comment: Just to understand what the actual problem is. It's that `a` by itself is not a valid statement, `a=a` just makes it a valid java statement, I'm not suggesting you do that, just explaining why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include z:

```
for(int i=a;i<=z;i++){
    [stuff]
}
```

or, if you want it to exclude z:

```
for(int i=a;i<z;i++)
    [stuff]
}
```

This is because the format for for loops is `for(int [counter]=[start value];[counter][condition][limit];[counter][change amount])`. For example, if you wanted something to loop up to (including) two, including zero, your code would be `for(int i=0; i<3;i++)`, while if you wanted it to loop down from two to zero it would be `for(int i=2; i>=0;i--)`.
To make the loop skip values just change the amount the counter increases/decreases by, such as `i+=2`, or `i-=2`

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers tell you how to fix it, but don't explain what the problem is. If you try to compile the class, you'll see the following error

```
$ javac SomeClass.java
SomeClass.java:16: error: not a statement
for(a ; a <= z ; a++) {
^
```

That's because `a` by itself is not a statement.

The simplest thing is to just omit the `a` since you don't need to initialize it

```
for(; a <= z ; a++) {}
```

Alternatively, you could create a looping variable so you don't affect `a` and you can initialize it in the loop so it looks more like a normal loop.

```
for(int i = a; i <= z ; i++) {}
```

Comment: [Language Specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) to answer your questions on commentaries. `ForInit`is a list of statements... Which lead us to some interesting quirks: `a++`is a statement / `a + 1` isn't; `getA()` is a statement / `new Integer(a)` is a statement and `a = a` is also a statement. Thankfully the Java Certification is not trying to enforce that level of knowledge about the language specs.

Comment: Juan. Actually no. Stating that `a` is not a statement is not the same as stating what `ForInit` is. Actually I'm even stating that  `ForInit` is not a statement according to the languages Specs:). I could write a statement about the purpose of my statements but I better not, further statements will induce everyone into a state of deeply confusion. Just don't assume that my statements are stating the obvious (they are only obvious to people that memorized the specs about statements :D). Trust me, I know my statements!

Comment: Good information. I'll consider addressing "what the problem is" more in future answers.